# Why this specific pasuk when returning the Torah to the Ahron?

Tags: tefilla, torah-service

Why was " Yehallulu es shaym hashem ..." specifically chosen to be said when we put the Torah **back** in the Ahron? And why does the shliach tzibur not complete the whole pasuk as is generally required when quoting a pasuk from Tanach?

Comment: Hi Zev. I made your title a bit more specific. Feel free to change it if it's not accurate.

Answer (score 4):

The *Sefer haRokeah* (Taamei B'rachos 319:274) says that his brother Chizkiyah explained that it's because we bow during birchas hatorah and we want to affirm afterwards that we weren't worshipping it but rather Hashem. The *Rokeah* also says (ibid. 273) that the call-and-response splitting of the passuq, like that of Kedushah, is designed to mimic the heavenly chorus.